# bash - How to make a process works while Skype is working

Tags: bash, scripting, process

I am trying to start a process while Skype is in progress. The script has to start Skype, and while Skype is running the process has to start working. When I close Skype, I want the process to turn off. I am trying to do this in a bash script.

My script is as following:

```
##############
#!/bin/bash
skype &
process &

PID=$(ps -opid= -C skype)
while [[ ( -d /proc/$PID ) && ( -z `grep zombie /proc/$PID/status` ) ]]; do
        sleep 1
done && killall process
```

The script passes through the "while" clause without stopping. While skype is running, the process has stopped.
Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
skype &
skypepid=$!

process &
processpid=$!

wait $skypepid
kill $processpid
```